# Styling track of slider range with a shape either side of halfway point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider, but need to style the track so that each side of the halfway point is a shape that colours depending on the position of the slider. I have absolutely no idea where to start with this so have no example code of what I have tried.

This is the design I have been given:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the design you have few options. The most common one is to have 2 svgs. The other one is to transform a div using CSS.

the starting point could be 0 (the center). based on the circle position you start styling the svg that it overlaps onto. We can say that from -1 to -100 we refer to the shape on the left and from 1 to 100 we refer to the shape on the right.

How to get the value based on the position of an element? When the mouse moves, we update the value based on the current position and the starting position (0). have a look at [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

If it's easier you could also think of it as:

1. 0% to 50% = -100 to 0
2. 50% to 100% = 0 to 100.

where the position of the element (i.e. 50%) is the position of the circle when using `transform: translateX(N)`.